# Decorator that does not catch exceptions properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, python-decorators, urllib3

I've experienced quite odd behaviour from decorator I wrote. It just has to catch errors occuring when a method tries to execute other methods relying on a connection to API.

Here is the decorator:

```py
from functools import wraps
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, HTTPError
from urllib3.exceptions import NewConnectionError, MaxRetryError
from typing import Optional, Union

def retry_on_failure(retries: Optional[int]=5, retry_interval: int=15):
    def _retry_on_failure(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            i = 1
            while retries is None or i <= retries:
                try:
                    print(f'This is try no. {i}')
                    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
                except (NewConnectionError, ConnectionError, HTTPError, MaxRetryError, TimeoutError):
                    print(f'Failed, retry in: {retry_interval}s')
                    i += 1
                    sleep(retry_interval)
        return wrapper
    return _retry_on_failure
```

And here is supposed method:

```py
@retry_on_failure()
def some_func():
    some_other_func_throwing_exc_when_api_not_available()
```

The problem is that I still get following exceptions in a stacktrace:

```
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f27588a1b00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='x.x.x.x', port=XXXX): Max retries exceeded with url: /some/api/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f27588a1b00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='x.x.x.x', port=XXXX): Max retries exceeded with url: /some/api/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f27588a1b00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

Just out of curiosity I tried catchin `Exception` and `BaseException`, but with no luck.

Does anyone know what might be a problem? Perhaps it's something very specific to `urllib3`?

Following code, after changing decorator to catch `KeyError`, works just fine...

```py
def f1():
    raise KeyError

@retry_on_failure()
def f2():
    f1()

f2()
```

Comment: You need to add `from time import sleep` to the top where you define your decorator.  More importantly, do you know that method is actually the source of the problem?  Taking your decorator implementation as-is and wrapping a function that raises `ConnectionError` works as intended, so it smells like something else is going on.

Comment: I am aware of sleep import, just forgot to add it here, thanks for your vigilence. ;-)

Seems like something `urllib`-specific. Another thing I was considering is that one of the method spawns a thread raising such exception, however the main thread fails so unlikely. I will keep looking.

Comment: It's interesting that you say that... because the way it is logged reminds me of an exception reaching the top of a thread, but you hadn't mentioned threads previously so I didn't mention it.  If an exception is raised in a different thread, then the exception is lost unless something captures it and passes it back to someone who cares.  What I mean is, if you're calling a method which spawns a thread and nothing is coordinating getting that exception back to the caller, then it is lost.  You can look at using something like futures to route it back to the caller.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

So far it seems that it is something related to urllib3 and sockets, so chances are that it is in fact in different thread.

Comment: Turned out it is super-specific to sockets, and catching exception one level higher does the job.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you post an answer then to explain what the solution was? By the way it's surprising that you're using such a decorator as urllib3 implements retries too (and throws MaxRetryError when all retries failed).